How to access AppDelegate from a class
During refactoring of a class that adopts the ObservableObject protocol to mark the class with the @Observable macro I'm encountering a problem with accessing the AppDelegate.
The AppDelegate looks like this.
class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var currentAuthorizationFlow: OIDExternalUserAgentSession?
}

In the main struct of my app the delegate is instantiated and managed by SwiftUI according to the example in the Apple docs.
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor private var appDelegate: AppDelegate

    var body: some Scene { ... }
}

In the class that I'm refactoring the AppDelegate is instantiated again. Although the Apple docs say it should only be instantiated once and only in the main of your app I'm not encountering any problems, everything works.
class AuthModel: ObservableObject {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate

    func login() async {
        await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
            appDelegate.currentAuthorizationFlow = OIDAuthState.authState(byPresenting: request, presenting: self) { authState, error in
                continuation.resume()
            }
        }
    }
}

I'm trying to refactor the AuthModel class to not use the @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor annotation (macro?) anymore so the main is the only place where the AppDelegate is instantiated and managed.
class AuthModel: ObservableObject {
    func login() async {
        await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
            let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
            appDelegate.currentAuthorizationFlow = OIDAuthState.authState(byPresenting: request, presenting: self) { authState, error in
                continuation.resume()
            }
        }
    }
}

This doesn't work, the app crashes at runtime on the line let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate with the error message Could not cast value of type 'SwiftUI.AppDelegate' (0x1ee8bafe8) to 'MyApp.AppDelegate' (0x1052a1c80). How can I access the app delegate from the AuthModel class?
Additional Info
The AuthModel is used throughout the app, mostly in views. One example is the login view.
struct LoginView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var authModel: AuthModel

    var body: some View {
        Button {
            Task {
                await authModel.login()
            }
        } label: {
            Text("Log in")
        }
        .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
    }
}


This is an XY Problem. Why are you trying to declare an app delegate adaptor in an @Observable class? It should only be declared in the App struct that is marked @main, and at most once.

What is the crash saying? If you are initiating the object inline with State the. State runs before the app delegate

Can you post your original and modified code ?

Thanks for revamping your question, it clarifies a bit what you are trying to do, but we still dont have all the code. I want to see how AuthModel is used. You should edit the title as well, as your problem has nothing to do with ObservableObject/@Observable. You are simply asking how to access the app delegate from an arbitrary class. See my comment on my answer.

It seems to me that you have been copy pasting code from the AppAuth docs without really understanding it. It is not clear whether you actually got something working at all.
From what I can gather, the AppAuth lib doesn't seem to be designed with SwiftUI in mind. It is a bit old fashion and requires hooking into the AppDelegate. A good starting point is to understand how to do this in a SwiftUI app. This is well explained in the doc for @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor.
Using code from the AppAuth docs, here is a simple SwiftUI implementation :
import SwiftUI
import AppAuth

@main
struct MyApp: App {
    
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject private var appDelegate: AppDelegate
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            appDelegate.login()
        } label: {
            Text("Login")
        }
    }
}

class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate, ObservableObject {
    
    var currentAuthorizationFlow: OIDExternalUserAgentSession?
    var authState: OIDAuthState?
    
    func login() {
        
        let authorizationEndpoint = URL(string: "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth")!
        let tokenEndpoint = URL(string: "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token")!
        let configuration = OIDServiceConfiguration(authorizationEndpoint: authorizationEndpoint, tokenEndpoint: tokenEndpoint)
        
        let request = OIDAuthorizationRequest(configuration: configuration,
                                              clientId: "<clientID>",
                                              clientSecret: "<clientSecret>",
                                              scopes: [OIDScopeOpenID, OIDScopeProfile],
                                              redirectURL: URL(string: "<redirectURL>")!,
                                              responseType: OIDResponseTypeCode,
                                              additionalParameters: nil)
        
        print("Initiating authorization request with scope: \(request.scope ?? "nil")")
        
        let scene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene
        let vc = scene!.keyWindow!.rootViewController!
        
        currentAuthorizationFlow = OIDAuthState.authState(byPresenting: request, presenting: vc) { authState, error in
            
            if let authState = authState {
                self.authState = authState
                print("Got authorization tokens. Access token: " +
                      "\(authState.lastTokenResponse?.accessToken ?? "nil")")
            } else {
                print("Authorization error: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")")
                self.authState = nil
            }
        }
    }
    
    func application(_ app: UIApplication,
                     open url: URL,
                     options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        
        if let authorizationFlow = self.currentAuthorizationFlow,
           authorizationFlow.resumeExternalUserAgentFlow(with: url) {
            
            self.currentAuthorizationFlow = nil
            return true
        }
        
        return false
    }
}


Yes, I did get it working using ObservableObject for my AuthModel class, but I'm having trouble getting it working using the @Observable macro. I'm still very much learning SwiftUI and regularly find that my understanding is not as solid as I initially thought. The idea was to have all authentication logic/code in a dedicated class, AuthModel, but I guess is makes sense to have it in the AppDelegate as that contains the session already. I'm not a big fan of the AppAuth library, as you said it doesn't seem designed for SwiftUI but it's recommended for the authentication flow I'm using

AppAuth is for OAuth and OpenID Connect, which one do you need? These are standards and you should be able to use any library that follows the spec.

Nothing prevents you from having your authentication logic/code in a dedicated class. You dont have to retrieve the app delegate from there, you can pass it in a function call or constructor as needed. Also I don't get why your AuthModel needs to be observable ?

@UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor should just be used in one place, e.g. in the App struct:
struct MyApp: App {

    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate

Then if you want to access it in other places first you should conform it to ObservableObject, e.g.
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, ObservableObject {

}

Then in your View models you can do:
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var appDelegate: AppDelegate

If you need the AppDelegate in an @Observable object then you could init the other object inside a lazy var inside AppDelegate and pass in weak self so it can access the delegate without a retain cycle.
Then if you wanted to observe that in a View model then in body you could init a child View model and pass in appDelegate.someObservable which would then use let someObservable and then if you access its properties in body the fact it is @Observable should take care of monitoring for update automatically, e.g.
@Observable
class MyObject {
    weak var appDelegate: AppDelegate?
    
    init(appDelegate: AppDelegate? = nil) {
        self.appDelegate = appDelegate
    }
}

class AppDelegate: AppDelegateSuperclass, ObservableObject {
    lazy var myObject: MyObject = MyObject(appDelegate: self)
    
}

struct SomeView: {
    let myObject: MyObject

    var body: some View {
        Text(myObject.text) // body should be called when text changes
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var appDelegate: AppDelegate

    var body: some View {
        SomeView(myObject: appDelegate.myObject)
    }
}

As you can see, objects are a bit of a nightmare to manage, so best stick to funcs and structs whenever you can in Swift/SwiftUI.

You should not mix @Observable and ObservableObject and certainly never one inside the other. The observable framework replaces the older ObservableObject.
See Managing model data in your app and Monitoring data and Migrating from the Observable Object

The OP is asking about AppDelegate not about model data and ObservableObject is the only way to make the AppDelegate available across the View hierarchy and there is no reason at all it can't hold an @Observable. Where did you hear you should not mix them?

FYI it would make more sense if you said @Observable replaces @Published.

OP's problem is to access AppDelegate from AuthModel, I think this answer shows a good way to achieve this.
